# Publishing an OWL File

Tags: php, semantics, owl

I made a OWL ontology using Protege, and I need to access it through PHP to make some SPARQL query. How do I create a local endpoint so I can call the ontology from PHP?

Answer (score 3):

[Fuseki](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/index.html) would probably work for your use case.

Comment: Can you list some other solutions?

Comment: Anything that supports the SPARQL protocol would do, Jena, Sesame, 4Store, BigData, OWLIM, Stardog, Virtuoso.

Comment: I need to write a simple program that gets a list of authors and books from a text file, and insert them as individuals in a OWL file, before relating them with a property like `isWrittenBy`, also present in the ontology (.owl file).

Do you know if it is all possible with Jena?

Comment: short answer is yes, but if you need more than that, you should start your own question.

Comment: It's OK. Jena only supports RDF and other formats, but not OWL. I had to convert my ontology to RDF.